# git revert / stash change without losing its history

Tags: git, github, git-checkout, git-stash

This is my requirement:
I have `a -> b -> c (HEAD)`. 
I am adding a new commit `d`. Now, it becomes `a -> b -> c -> d(HEAD)`.

Now, I want to revert to `c` (that is, undoing all changes that were made in `d`) and make an additional change and form `e`. The tree should look like `a -> b-> c -> d -> e(HEAD)`. NOTE: I must not lose the `d` history. I must revert it and add new changes to `e`.

**UPDATE:**
I can explain with a better example. Let's say I have `a->b->c(HEAD)`, here `c` is the primary or main commit. *I'm trying to automate with a script.*

**Initial Step:** I start with `git checkout <SHA1 of c>`, tree looks like: `a->b->c(DETACHED HEAD)`

**My Real query starts from here:**

1. I **modify few files (I don't add any new files)** and add a new commit `d`. So tree should look like: `a->b->c->d(HEAD)`
2. I **revert changes in #1** by running **Initial Step** and *modify other files (again, I don't add any new files)* and add a new commit `e`. So tree should look like: `a->b->c->d->e(HEAD)`

**NOTE:** Here `e` = revert of commit `d` + new changes to `c`. I can't blindly use `git revert HEAD` since `c` is considered to be the primary commit. I was thinking I could use `git stash` and `git stash pop` to remove old changes and insert new changes. Can I do something like `git checkout stash`?

**In short:** I'm trying to fuzz test commit `c` for around 50 times (ie) commit and revert for 50 times

Comment: So what happens when you do `git revert HEAD`?

Comment: @Makoto: it (`git revert HEAD^`)  reverts the changes in `c` as a new commit.  He wants `git revert HEAD`

Comment: @ChrisDodd:  Fair point.  I usually get those mixed up.  In my defense, I don't use `revert` very often...

Answer (score 3):

The `git revert` command does precisely what you describe as desired -- it creates a new change on the top of the current branch that reverses some previout change.  In your case

```
git revert HEAD
```

will create a new change (your `e`) on top of `HEAD` that reverses what was changed in `HEAD` (`d`)

Comment: This will create a commit that undoes a change. I need to add new changes to the commit `e`. That is, `e` has new changes + reverted code

Comment: If you need to add changes to a commit, use `git commit --amend`.  If you need to combine the last two commits into a single commit, use `git rebase -i HEAD~2`

Answer (score 0):

What about

First commit changes made to d

```
$ git commit -d "Your message"
```

Then create new branch e on c and checkout Something like

```
 $ git checkout -b e c
```

Comment: seems like this would work. But it would lead to handling lot of branches. I have updated the question with an example

Comment: other option would be `git -stash` instead of commit it would note:- this will create a stack of changes mean it will keep history but you can't directly switch between histories you can get in to history one by one `stash pop`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put additional changes to the revert commit as well, [use `-n` flag in revert command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#git-revert--n):

```
git revert -n HEAD
```

This will revert the changes in HEAD but will not create a commit, so you can make your additional changes and commit when you are done.